# How to calculate the modified date for a specific column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list in SharePoint where people will change the status to "closed" when complete. I want to have a column that populates the date this column was changed to "closed"

Sometimes entry is changed after being closed, so I can't always rely on the "last modified" view

Answer (score 0):

If you have versioning enabled, you will see what columns have changed exactly when you look at version history.

Answer (score 0):

Besides versioning, you could create a workflow associated with the list to log history into workflow history list.
[image]